# Typescript definition, this, and inheritance misunderstanding

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am working on creating a definition to represent an existing package on npm (gui).

I need need to implement the following:

```
class A {
    onEventA: (self: this) => void;
    static create(): A;
}

class B extends A {
    onEventB: (self: this) => void;
    static create(): B;
}
```

I am getting the following issue:

```
TS2417: Class static side of 'typeof B' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof A'.
  Types of property 'create' are incompatible.
    Type '() => B' is not assignable to type '() => A'.
      Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'A'.
        Types of property 'onEventA' are incompatible.    
          Type '(self: B) => void' is not assignable to type '(self: A) => void'.
            Types of parameters 'self' and 'self' are incompatible.
              Property 'onEventB' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'B'
```

Now if I change it to:

```
class A {
    onEventA(self: this): void;
    static create(): A;
}

class B extends A {
    onEventB(self: this): void;
    static create(): B;
}
```

The error goes away.

Why does defining them as methods work, but defining them as properties fail?

Comment: With strict or strict function types turned on?

Comment: Looks like polymorphic `this` [breaks](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28476) inheritance-based subtyping on purpose.  Methods don't enforce parameter contravariance so there's no error, but `--strict` function-typed properties do, and it's broken.  Interesting issue but apparently everything works as intended.

Comment: @jcalz I was writing up an answer but my boarding just completed :-D. If you want you can write it up :-)

Comment: I might not get to it either... if you get there first, be my guest.

Comment: I do have "strict" turned on.